# I have been trying to identify a metal/rock act for almost 24 years

Tags: metal, japan, black-metal

In the year 2000 (more or less) I received a CD-RW from a friend (so no labels on the CD) in a jewel case that was wrongly labelled "Sabbat - Black up your soul". Although the CD had the same number of tracks (16) as the Sabbat one, the band is not Sabbat. I can't remember the lyrics of any of the songs as my knowledge of English was very limited at the time, but I do remember that the singer's voice made me think he had a weird Japanese/Asian accent even when singing in English. The sound was raw with most black and thrash metal elements, but there were also some light symphonic pieces in some songs; I also remember that the last track had a funny voice and a different sound, so it was probably a cover of a song by another band.

Any helpful information will be very welcome.

Comment: Identification questions are no longer on-topic here, unfortunately.